# How do I fix the gap between my view and my navigation bar when the call status bar is active?

Tags: uinavigationbar, ecslidingviewcontroller, ios7-statusbar

I am using ECSlidingViewController for navigation but I don't believe this is the cause of my problem. Below is an example of my problem.

---

[image]

---

I have tried using viewDidLayoutSubviews to fix this and I have changed the settings for navigationBar translucency to NO. I thought with proper constraints in my view that auto layout would handle something like this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I am getting same error like this did you found any solution for this ??

Comment: As of right now I don't have any firm solution. I may try persisting the view controller when I segue back to the main menu. It seems that the error only happens after a segue back to the main menu view. I think the issue maybe there.

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad`, add:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```